# Grouping by sequence and then finding minimum value in a column

Tags: r, aggregate, tidyverse

I have a data set that amoungst other columns has `date, sequence and low` columns, please see `df` below.
The sequence from `1-to-9` is considered one block or one full cycle in the `sequence` column
The data set has several such complete block/cycles and partially completed ones, `eg: 1-to-4`

This is what I'm trying to solve:

1. Remove the partly completed cycles and then group the full cycles (see `df1`)
2. For each block/cycle (i.e. sequence from 1-to-9), I want to find the
   low of the block along with the day the low was happened.
3. If there are two lows with same value but on different dates, then
   it should only output the latest date (see the 3rd block in output)

   ```
   library(lubridate)
   library(tidyverse)
   ### Sample data
   df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
   date = c("1/01/2019", "2/01/2019", "3/01/2019", "4/01/2019",
   "5/01/2019", "6/01/2019", "7/01/2019", "8/01/2019",
   "9/01/2019", "10/01/2019", "11/01/2019", "12/01/2019", "13/01/2019",
   "14/01/2019", "15/01/2019", "16/01/2019", "17/01/2019", "18/01/2019",
   "19/01/2019", "20/01/2019", "21/01/2019", "22/01/2019",
   "23/01/2019", "24/01/2019", "25/01/2019", "26/01/2019", "27/01/2019",
   "28/01/2019", "29/01/2019", "30/01/2019", "31/01/2019",
   "1/02/2019", "2/02/2019", "3/02/2019", "4/02/2019"),
   sequence = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,
   9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9),
   low = c(96, 81, 43, 18, 43, 65, 48, 90, 69, 50, 41, 73, 1, 1, 7, 49,
   16, 79, 2, 74, 8, 88, 56, 57, 66, 29, 79, 51, 52, 47, 42, 9,
   41, 9, 50)) %>% mutate(date = dmy(date))
   ```

   #### Data grouped by cycle/block

   ```
   df1 <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
       date = c("1/01/2019", "2/01/2019", "3/01/2019", "4/01/2019",
                "5/01/2019", "6/01/2019", "7/01/2019", "8/01/2019",
                "9/01/2019", "14/01/2019", "15/01/2019", "16/01/2019", "17/01/2019",
                "18/01/2019", "19/01/2019", "20/01/2019", "21/01/2019", "22/01/2019",
                "27/01/2019", "28/01/2019", "29/01/2019", "30/01/2019",
                "31/01/2019", "1/02/2019", "2/02/2019", "3/02/2019", "4/02/2019"),
   sequence = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3,
                4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9),
        low = c(96, 81, 43, 18, 43, 65, 48, 90, 69, 1, 7, 49, 16, 79, 2, 74,
                8, 88, 79, 51, 52, 47, 42, 9, 41, 9, 50),
      group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3,
                3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)) %>% mutate(date = dmy(date))
   ```

Final output I am after

```
  df_final <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
         date = c("4/01/2019", "14/01/2019", "3/02/2019"),
          low = c(18, 1, 9)) %>% mutate(date = dmy(date))
```

Any ideas?
Ps. I ran into some problems formatting this question, hence the untidiness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We create the grouping variable by taking the cumulative sum where sequence is 1, then `filter` only the groups with 9 elements, and `slice` the rows where the 'low' is minimum after `arrange`ing the 'date' in `desc`ending order to take care of cases where there are ties for the 'low'est value

```
df %>% 
   group_by(group = cumsum(sequence == 1)) %>% 
   filter(n() == 9) %>% 
   select(date, low) %>%
   arrange(desc(date)) %>%
   slice(which.min(low)) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(-group)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  date         low
#  <date>     <dbl>
#1 2019-01-04    18
#2 2019-01-14     1
#3 2019-02-03     9
```

---

Or similar option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[.N == 9], .(group = cumsum(sequence == 1))
          ][order(-date), .SD[which.min(low)], group]
```

Comment: @cephalopod  Can you check the output

Comment: the last value 9 should have date of `2019-02-03`

Answer (score 2):

Another `dplyr` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(group = cumsum(sequence == 1), rleid = with(rle(group), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths))) %>%
 filter(all(c(1:9) %in% sequence)) %>%
 slice(which.min(rank(low, ties.method = "last"))) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 select(-group, -rleid)

  date       sequence   low
  <date>        <dbl> <dbl>
1 2019-01-04        4    18
2 2019-01-14        1     1
3 2019-02-03        8     9
```

Here it, first, creates a cumulative sum of "sequence" == 1 and a `rleid()`-like variable based on the cumulative sum and then performs the grouping by the two. Second, it removes the cases where a sequence does not contain all of the nine values. Finally, it returns the minimum value per group, in the case of ties returning the last minimum value (you can modify it by the argument `ties.method`).

Comment: I went with `Akrun` as his code is easier for me to understand. Wish I could upvote your answer more than once though!

Answer (score 1):

This is also possible in base R. Might be a little *map*sy, though.

```
w <- which(df$sequence == 1)
w <- w[sapply(w, function(x) df$sequence[x + 8] == 9 & sum(df$sequence[x:(x + 8)]) == 45)]
do.call(rbind, Map(function(x) x[which.min(x$low), ], 
                   Map(function(s) df[s, ], Map(seq, w, l=9))))
#          date sequence low
# 4  2019-01-04        4  18
# 14 2019-01-14        1   1
# 32 2019-02-01        6   9
```

The trick is to find the completed sequences and group them in a list, then `rbind` the `which.min` of each group. The `sum(.) == 45` check should take account if there actually isn't a false sequence.

***Data***

```
df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(17897, 17898, 17899, 17900, 
17901, 17902, 17903, 17904, 17905, 17906, 17907, 17908, 17909, 
17910, 17911, 17912, 17913, 17914, 17915, 17916, 17917, 17918, 
17919, 17920, 17921, 17922, 17923, 17924, 17925, 17926, 17927, 
17928, 17929, 17930, 17931), class = "Date"), sequence = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), low = c(96, 81, 43, 18, 
43, 65, 48, 90, 69, 50, 41, 73, 1, 1, 7, 49, 16, 79, 2, 74, 8, 
88, 56, 57, 66, 29, 79, 51, 52, 47, 42, 9, 41, 9, 50)), row.names = c(NA, 
-35L), class = "data.frame")
```